# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

When i run my application i get this error.

Here is my userForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
.even {
    background-color: silver;
}
</style>
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="add.htm" commandName="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender :</td>
            <td><form:radiobutton path="gender" value="M" label="M" /> <form:radiobutton
                path="gender" value="F" label="F" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country :</td>
            <td><form:select path="country">
                <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
                <form:option value="India" label="India" />
                <form:option value="USA" label="USA" />
                <form:option value="UK" label="UK" />
            </form:select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>About you :</td>
            <td><form:textarea path="aboutYou" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Community :</td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="community" value="Spring"
                label="Spring" /> <form:checkbox path="community" value="Hibernate"
                label="Hibernate" /> <form:checkbox path="community" value="Struts"
                label="Struts" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="mailingList"
                label="Would you like to join our mailinglist?" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<c:if test="${fn:length(userList) > 0}">
    <table cellpadding="5">
        <tr class="even">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>About You</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user" varStatus="status">
            <tr class="<c:if test="${status.count % 2 == 0}">even</c:if>">
                <td>${user.name}</td>
                <td>${user.gender}</td>
                <td>${user.country}</td>
                <td>${user.aboutYou}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

and below is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringExample17</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/04/24/how-to-reference-and-use-jstl-in-your-web-application/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043869/intellij-and-jsp-jstl-cannot-resolve-taglib-for-jstl-in-tomcat7/32444393#32444393

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that JSTL is not installed. Just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and restart server.