# IntelliJ and JSP/JSTL cannot resolve taglib for JSTL in tomcat7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, jstl

First of all my JSTl code works on my server because i have the proper Jar file in the Lib folder in tomcat7.  This is just really an IDEA problem.  My questions comes down to where i put the same jar file in my file directory within IntelliJ.

I have ran into a error in IntelliJ and JSTL.

My problem is that when i use

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

It results in Cannot resolve taglib with uri.  I have tried different Jar files and I do know that i have to correct version for my servlet.

Im running tomcat7 on Ubuntu Server 15.04, and IntelliJ 14.1.3.

I have tried importing the jar file though the Project Structure, and including it in various places but still the same error after re-building the project, and closing down and reopening the IDEA.

This sample code runs when deployed to tomcat but IntelliJ keeps giving errors.

```
<table border="1">
    <c:forEach var="a" items="${data}">
        <tr>
            <td>${a}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

<c:forEach begin="0" end="255" var="i">
    <span style='color:rgb(
        <c:out value="${i}"/>,
        <c:out value="${i}"/>,
        <c:out value="${i}"/>);'>
        <c:out value="${i}"/></span> <br />
</c:forEach>
```

I would like to know how to stop IntelliJ from giving errors on my Syntax even though the code works.

I have read [JSTL in IntelliJ gives errors in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253034/jstl-in-intellij-gives-errors-in-jsp)

and

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jsp_editor.html

Still no luck.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

First add this to the top of your `.jsp` file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

It will still give syntax error but you can fix that by adding `javax.servlet:jstl:1.2` as a module dependency. To do that, follow these steps:

1. Click your project name and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the module settings dialog.
2. Then go to the `dependencies` tab in the `modules` section.
3. Click the green `+` icon `→` library `→` From Maven.
4. Search for `javax.servlet:jstl:1.2` in the search bar and press OK and it will download and add the above mentioned library as a module.
5. Now you should not have any kind of syntax error.

Comment: @ShamsUIAzeem after adding it gives me `The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` how to fix it

Comment: In my case adding the dependency `javax.servlet:jstl:1.2` **didn't work.** Adding the dependency `jstl:jstl:1.2` worked.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using maven, add following code in pom.xml inside the `<dependencies></dependencies>` tag

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to add `<scope>runtime</scope>` in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still getting errors after following the instructions provided by Shams UI Azeem, you may need to add the JSTL library to the WAR Exploded artifact.  To do this:

1. Go to Project Structure.  Under Project Settings, select Artifacts.  On the bottom of the menu box, there may be a message which mentions that the JSTL library used is not included in the WAR.

2a.  **Message visible.**  If the message is displayed, there should be a Fix button next to it.  Click this Fix button.  Select "add `javax.servlet:jstl:1.2` to the artifact".

2b.  **Message not visible.**  If the message is not displayed, then look above to see if the `javax.servet:jstl:1.2 (Project Library)` is underneath the Available Elements column.  If it is, right click it and select "Put into /WEB-INF/lib".

If you are working with Maven, the Fix message will not appear, though you will still need to do this.

Comment: My problem was solved following the comment of Arpan Srivastava and then following this answer of @Jack J.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there because by default jstl jar is added for scope **Compile Time Only** We need to make it to get added for **Runtime** to do that.

1. Click your project name and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the module settings dialog **or** Right Click on Project name and find **Open Module Settings**.
2. Go to the dependencies tab in the modules section.
3. Find the `javax.servlet:jstl:x.x`, look at its scope, change it to **Runtime**.
4. Also, you need to add `jstl:jar` to `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: I had to click on the + button and link it to JSTL jar in my WEB-INF folder, then change to runtime

Answer (score 1):

As per Maven Repository, **javax.servlet:jstl** has moved to **javax.servlet.jsp.jstl**, however the later does not fix the URI resolution issue.

Adding the old **javax.servlet:jstl** dependency solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work using these:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```