# Cannot resolve taglib with uri in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, jstl, taglib

By looking at the tutorial series `JSP, Servlets and JDBC for Beginners: Build a Database App` on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/jsp-tutorial/learn/v4/content) done by `Chad Darby` and with the help of [BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r/) I wrote the following code in `Intellij IDEA`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%--To use JSTL core tags we need to import the following URL with prefix--%>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<%
    // need to define a sample array
    String cities[]={"City1","City2","City3","City4"};
    // to use JSTL tags they have a to be a part of an attribute, either in the scope of the pageContext, session or application
    pageContext.setAttribute("myCities",cities);

%>
<body>
<%-- for printing them in for each loop--%>
<c:forEach var="cityName" items="${myCities}" >
    <%-- here we are using JSP expression language as ${...}}--%>
    ${cityName} <br/>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

and add the `JSTL` libs under `WEB-INF/lib` as suggested by both the author of the tutorial (note: tutorial is done on `Eclipse IDE`) and `BalusC` answer. The code works fine, but `IDEA` editor give me

> cannot resolve taglib with uri http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

and

> cannot resolve symbol 'c:forEach'

and those lines are in red color as seen in the image[image: below]

Why is this happening?. Is there any other place to add those libraries in `IDEA`? Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32444393/104891. JSTL library seems to be missing from the dependencies.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks, it removed the red colored lines. Do we need to do both in order for `JSTL` work on `IDEA` I mean adding libraries to `WEB-INF/lib` and adding the dependencies as you have suggested?

Comment: You just add the libraries to the dependencies and then these dependencies can be included into the artifact if your web container doesn't already provide them, otherwise you set the scope of the libraries to Provided and do not include them in the artifact.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar kind of message while working with spring based project. I resolved it by adding following dependencies inside pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

next open terminal and then do maven clean install

```
mvn -U clean install
```