# Jstl jar. not registering

Tags: java, jstl

I've been trying to figure out why my **jstl** jar refuses to register in all my projects' exploded war directories. When I run my application in localhost it works fine, but when i create my war file it fails to register. I have already rebuilt the project, but I get the same result. Any ideas?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

The `uri` is red and says `"cannot resolve taglib"`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by register?  Are you saying that you are receiving an error when running your application? If so share the error message you are receiving.  What servlet container are you using?  It sounds like you are having an issue in your IDE not resolving taglibs uri instead of a real error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ and JSP/JSTL cannot resolve taglib for JSTL in tomcat7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043869/intellij-and-jsp-jstl-cannot-resolve-taglib-for-jstl-in-tomcat7)

Comment: I don't get an error thrown from this, but when I upload my war I can't see any of my content and that usually happens when I have an error with my jstl code.

Comment: If you can't see anything on the page then either you have not properly deployed your JSPs, you are not hitting the correct url, or your config hides errors. By default tomcat and the others show big error messages when there is an issue with the JSP code.  Check your tomcat logs and make sure your app is actually deploying.

Comment: Turns out the jstl error only affects one page in my website. And on that page, at first, most of my js worked, but now only some of my js works. Almost like its spreading like a virus cutting off my js. my js shows in the source code so i dont think its a jstl error. Also my tomcat logs do not show an error.

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with your generated html/javascript.  If you got a 200 response your server side code is at least executing.

Comment: My source code shows that an element is there, but doesn't actually show the element. Weird.

Comment: That tends to happen on an invalid html page. Try validating the html source and fixing issues