# INTELLIJ can't resolve JSTL taglib

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, jstl

I have a problem with adding `JSTL` in `.jsp` file. 
I'm working in `INTELLIJ` and using `TOMCAT 9.0.12`.
Intellij can't resolve `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Libraries are located in

> web/WEB-INF/lib

**Error**:

[image]

**Directory :**

[image]

Should I change something in `web.xml`?
I'm learning `JSP` and can't find solution for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ and JSP/JSTL cannot resolve taglib for JSTL in tomcat7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043869/intellij-and-jsp-jstl-cannot-resolve-taglib-for-jstl-in-tomcat7)

Comment: add 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2' jar and it will work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't add correct jar in you lib folder. In order to use this tag you should use `jstl` library. To get this jar go [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2). And click download jar file from this link. And then copy this jar in lib folder

Comment: @AvijtBarua yes, my problem was linked with INTELLIJ. When I added jar to WEB-INF/lib he was executed by JSP, but wasn't visible for IDE. I solved problem by adding my jstl jar to project libraries in INTELLIJ at least for now.

Comment: Actually I wrote the same as you wanted in my answer :D !